# how to re-start from package from where it stopped on user selection

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008, msbi

We have a Master SSIS package and it calls few other child packages and some tasks,We have UI portal build for it to start the master package and to check the status of the package.Whenever package fails(i.e.because of network issues or other errors which can be rectified by user.) at particular task either in master package or in child package. User will be provided with two options  Start/Resume on UI for that package. If he selects Resume, package should start from where it stopped previously. If he selects Start, package should start from the beginning.

I thought of to achieve this by using check points in ssis, but my question is what if the child package got failed. so when user selects resume the master package, it should start from failed task in child package which is being called in master package. Sometimes user may want to start from the beginning and selects start, check points should be disabled and it should start from beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use transactions in sequence containers of the child packages. Also enable checkpoints.
So, when any error occurs the transaction will be rolled back for the container and the checkpoint will enable re-execution from a user defined location. The transaction in turn, will rollback the part which throws exception.

Comment: what if user doesnt select resume, and wants start from begginning. so package should start from starting point.

Comment: then you can declare a global user variable as boolean, assign the checkpoint status to the user value in script task. Now you can change the value of the variable in package config (xml) at runtime to use checkpoints or not based on user preference

Comment: i tried using given suggestion.For suppose, Master Package contains below tasks. 1)[Execute SQL Task 1] 2)[Execute SQL Task 2] 3)[Execute Package Task 1]  4)[Execute SQL Task 3] 5)[Execute Package Task 2].  if a package fails at a particular task in child package  [Execute Package Task 1]. next time it is running from [Execute SQL Task 3] instead of [Execute Package Task 1].

Comment: Use precedence constraint for success or failure if your scenario is such (Precedence Constraint for both success and failure). In this way you can redirect failed part to any next part (Here the Execute package or Execute Sql)

Comment: No, it wont solve my problem. if a package fails at particular task, if we are running the package again, it should start from the point of failure. but it starting from the next task. In the above example given, it suppossed to start from  [Execute Package Task 1] but it is starting from [Execute SQL Task 3].

Comment: I need to view the package in order to give you a solution